# Detect ui-grid value within Angular UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

That's my grid

```
<div
    ui-grid="myAPI.myGrid"
    ui-grid-pinning
    ui-grid-pagination
    ui-grid-resize-columns
    class="gridMid">
</div>
```

How can I detect `"myAPI.myGrid"` within the grid?

(Click on row/column/cell/button/whatever/.. should e.g. alert `"myAPI.myGrid"`)

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Are you asking if you can retrieve the name of the grid from inside your logic?

Comment: e.g. inside of a cellTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `ui-grid` directive attribute is called `gridOptions`, you can retrieve the `options` property straight from the `grid` object: `grid.options`.

You can use the grid object in your custom templates flawlessly, just refer to it, as explained in the [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/317_custom_templates):

> In the cellTemplate you have access to grid, row and column, which
>   allows you to write any of a range of functions.

So just calling `grid.options` inside your template should do it, and if you need to get the data array just go with `grid.options.data`

If you need to get a reference to the `grid` object elsewhere you can get it from your `gridApi` objects (look [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#properties_onregisterapi) for more info about gridApi) simply with `gridApi.grid`

**EDIT**: Added plunker and clarification.

I've built [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCe1QJgisUTaJLAgVsy2?p=preview) where I pass the object to a `clickFn` inside of the controller's scope, just need to click on any cell in the last column.

Beware that when I talked about the grid's name in my comment to your question, I was quite inaccurate: there is no concept like a grid name, but, as I said before in this answer, what you called `myApi.myGrid` is just a reference to an object, so you can only pass/retrieve that object, not the name you gave to that reference.

I guess this is not a problem, since what you will eventually need is the object. If you want to inspect it, just place a breakpoint inside `clickFn` in my plunkr.

**EDIT**: Added new plunker

I created a [new plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kl917uIjfa0DsEPIsyHV?p=preview) where clickFn function behaves like a "Delete" button.

Comment: Thank you, but I read that already, can you give me an example: Click on a button within a cellTemplate should alert its gridname, in my case above "myAPI.myGrid". A code excerpt would be enough for me.

Comment: I saw your edit and I've already inspected it: there is no single information about the grid model name, which was given in the html view in Form of:  `ui-grid="my.grid.model.name.in.my.scope"`

Comment: that's because "my.grid.model.name.in.my.scope" is a reference and not just a string. May I ask you why you need that string?

Comment: Why I am asking the question: I would like to create a single view and replace grid name with the corresponding services in the rest api, so that all the services get a crud functionality, without knowing their name or structure. I want to automate all these functionalities.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how can you delete in your case the current row? Do you need to detect the index before? If yes, you need the model name, don't you?

Comment: Not at all, you have the model object, and inside of the object the data property contains the rows array. You should just remove a row from that array

Comment: That would solve my problem too. What is the name of the Command "delete current row" ?

Comment: I created a new plunker, see second edit in the answer

Comment: You need an Index, but `index = grid.options.data.indexOf(row.entity);` is an acceptable solution, because I don't necessarily detect the model name. Thank you!

Comment: I was implementing it and have noticed I still need the model name for ngResource :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98653/discussion-between-imbalind-and-vienna).